# how to force all double precision in 64-bit (and not any 80-bit registers)

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a numerical package to give the same results on two different platforms (linux and macos) in order to rule out bugs/hardware problems.  I suspect the current source of differences is different 64-bit vs. 80-bit double precision arithmetic.  I know there are compiler options for gcc to control this but I thought there was also a function call to set this, as well as something that can be done on the command line or shell environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are both on the same machine?

Comment: And of course, you will still get different results if you use different versions of the compiler (or C library) to compute the results. x86 will ALWAYS use 80-bit registers to perform the calculation, but you can set the floating point control register to make all intermediate calculations round to 64-bit. 

Of course, if one compiler decides to use SSE and the other doesn't, all bets are off!

Comment: Note that doing this typically kills performance. Java originally imposed this requirement, and got screams of protest from the numerics folks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so assuming you are on x86, using floating point, you should set bits 9-8 in the x87 register FCW to 10b. [This is also what Windows does by default for some reason].

Something like this should work in gcc:

```
void set_fp_mode()
{
    short mode;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("fstcw %0\n"
               "andw   $0xFEFF, %0\n"       // Clear bit 8. 
               "orw    $0x200, %0\n"        // just to be safe, set bit 9.
               "fldcw %0\n" : : "m" (mode));
}
```

[Where I worked several years ago, someone complained that their new computer wasn't as good at floating point as the old one, and gave me a dump of the binary results from both. I got a similar computer to the customers old computer and one like the new, and I couldn't make it go different - until I realized that one machine was running windows, the other wasn't, so the floating point results were "better" on the non-windows machine. After I gave the customer a very similar piece of code to the above, but that set both bit 8 and 9 to make 80-bit precision, the customer was happy!]

Comment: Thanks for the code.  This doesn't compile for me with gcc on MACOS (lion).  Complaint about missing " terminator.  Adding extra "'s doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Updated the code to something that compiles - I must admit I haven't tested it - it's a little tricky to tell the difference anyways.